# How to trigger Ajax call based on text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to trigger my Ajax function when any of the text fields are changed.. I'm totally new to Ajax so I don't know how or if this is possible.. Any help will be very appreciated!

**Html**

```
<form>
    <a>Enter Item ID 1:</a> 
    <input id="target1" type="text" name="itemID" required />   
    <br>
    <a>Enter Item ID 2:</a> 
    <input id="target2" type="text" name="itemID2"/>    
    <div class="result"></div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#target').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'shelfid.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{ 
                itemID: $(this).val() 
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $(".result").text(data);    
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with above code? Are you getting any exception?

Comment: You just need the ID of the element to actually match the ID you use in the jQuery selector. (Voting to close as "caused by a typo").

Comment: There is no errors in the code. The code is created for one field only.. As I can't seem to find any good solution for multiple fields i'm trying to see if anyone here know how to do. @DhavalMarthak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery selector used is wrong. You should use `$('input[type=text]')` to select all text fields instead of `$('#target')`

Comment: Well it works now, I just have to modify the result so it doesn't delete the latest one! Thanks!

Comment: An answer in less that two minutes; a correct answer in less than two minutes.

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass Well my questions are at the stage of kindergarden :P